# How to upload a file in Flask RESTful using cURL?

Tags: python, python-3.x, curl, flask-restful

I have written the next `Resource`:

```
from config import AWS_S3_BUCKET
from flask_api import status
from flask_restful import Resource, reqparse
from werkzeug.datastructures import FileStorage
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
import helpers


class FileUpload(Resource):

    def post(self):
        parse = reqparse.RequestParser()
        parse.add_argument('user_file', type=FileStorage, location='user_file')
        parse.add_argument('user_id', type=int, location='user_id')
        args = parse.parse_args()
        file = args['user_file']
        if file:
            file.filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            url = helpers.upload_file_to_s3(file, AWS_S3_BUCKET)
            return {'url': url}, status.HTTP_201_CREATED

        return 'Invalid file', status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
```

After I'm trying to upload my file in cURL by this command:

```
curl -F 'user_file=@recovery.fstab' -F 'user_id=5' http://127.0.0.1:5000/files/new
```

In the debugger the endpoint is called but all fields: `user_file` and `user_id` are `NoneType`.
What am I doing wrong?
**P.S.** The `recovery.fstab` file is located in the `home` directory.

Answer (score 1):

See the [flask-RESTful docs](http://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.5/reqparse.html#argument-locations).

Location argument is where req parser get the values from.

```
def post(self):
    parse = reqparse.RequestParser()
    parse.add_argument('user_file', type=FileStorage, location='files')
    parse.add_argument('user_id', type=int, location='args')
    ...
```